# Google Places Autocomplete (included with Places Details) SKU is not getting triggered while using session tokens

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I am making requests to the Google places autocomplete and details api. For both I am using session tokens to use the autocomplete api charge free, but I don't see the `Autocomplete (included with Places Details) SKU` in the Google report. I started using it a week ago and all I see is the `SKU: Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session`.

In my code I am generating a new version 4 UUID compliant session token after a request to the details api is made. I am following the guidelines in the docs that say this:

[image: The workflow]

So I am doing that exact thing. But I don't see the `Autocomplete (included with Place Details)` in the report. I am sure a lot of calls have been made. Any ideas why this is happening?

Note: Instead of `placeid` I am using `place_id` parameter for the details call which also works. I don't think that's the reason but anyways...

I am using this function to generate the session tokens:

```
var UUID = (function() {
  var self = {};
  var lut = [];
  for (var i=0; i<256; i++) { lut[i] = (i<16?'0':'')+(i).toString(16); }
  self.generate = function() {
      var d0 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      var d1 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      var d2 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      var d3 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      return lut[d0&0xff]+lut[d0>>8&0xff]+lut[d0>>16&0xff]+lut[d0>>24&0xff]+'-'+
        lut[d1&0xff]+lut[d1>>8&0xff]+'-'+lut[d1>>16&0x0f|0x40]+lut[d1>>24&0xff]+'-'+
        lut[d2&0x3f|0x80]+lut[d2>>8&0xff]+'-'+lut[d2>>16&0xff]+lut[d2>>24&0xff]+
        lut[d3&0xff]+lut[d3>>8&0xff]+lut[d3>>16&0xff]+lut[d3>>24&0xff];
  }
  return self;
})();
```

It outputs a string in a format like this: `a28cf301-d8fd-4ebd-ac25-a94a37113b6c`.

I am using a leaflet control to make the requests.

The following function is called each time a letter is typed:

```
// Places Autocomplete call
autocomplete: function(e) {
    var mapCenter = this._map.getCenter();
    var url = this.options.url + '/autocomplete?' +
        'input=' + this.input.value + '&' +
        'location=' + mapCenter.lat + ',' + mapCenter.lng;

    if (this.options.useSessions) {
        url += '&sessiontoken=' + this.sessionToken;
    }

    var geocoder = this;

    $.get(url, function(data, status) {
        if (data === undefined || data.status !== 'OK') {
            return;
        }

        // Use predictions to populate a list
    });
},
```

That function populates a list with the predictions and add click event listeners to each list item. When an item is clicked the following function is called.

```
// Place Details request
focusSelected: function(e) {
    var url = this.options.url + '/details?' +
        'place_id=' + e.target.place_id;

    if (this.options.useSessions) {
        url += '&sessiontoken=' + this.sessionToken;
        this.sessionToken = UUID.generate(); // This creates a new token
    }

    var geocoder = this;
    $.get(url, function(data, status) {
        if (data === undefined || data.status !== 'OK') {
            return;
        }

        // Use result

    });
},
```

I am also setting the API key in each call. Don't mind about that.

Answer (score -1):

You will see `Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session` if you don't complete a `Places Details` request within a few minutes of starting the session.

#### Documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#ac-no-details-session

Comment: There are a lot of times I am doing a place details request  after several autocomplete requests.

Comment: Are you making sure to use the same session id for all requests? Or are you generating a new session id per?

Comment: I use only one token at a time. I do several autocomplete requests with token ABC, then one place details with the same token ABC. Each time I am done with a place details request I generate a new session token for the next autocomplete or details requests.

Comment: I added some code. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I just tossed together your code into a demo and it appears it should function correctly. Have you checked out the network requests to verify the correct session token is being sent? Also, have you tried just hard coding the 3 requests in the screenshot you provided to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the actual requests and the session tokens look good there. And I also tried manually doing the requests (just once). But still I can only see  the `without Place Details` SKU

Comment: Also, I don't see any feedback about the sessions in the API responses. Google should take care of that.

Comment: @Michael are you able to fixed it... same things happening with me
Please help