# Google Places Autocomplete example using Javascript with a Places Session Token

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am trying to get Google places Autocomplete to work with sessions, but I can't find an example anywhere that uses them. I am getting 10-20 or more hits to my API billing every search. I guess it is everytime a new letter is added to the search box. 
As I understand it, sessions should group these so that I am only billed once per search, rather than per letter typed.
This example also states in the comments that it uses the autocomplete widget, which I have searched for information on, and it appears it should automatically implement sessions.

Does anyone have an example how to use sessions in javascript for google places autocomplete calls? Or know why I am getting billed for each letter?

The example that I am using is below.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
        font-family: "Roboto";
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f9ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete"
             placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()"
             type="text"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Note: The address components in this sample are typical. You might need to adjust them for
               the locations relevant to your app. For more information, see
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
    -->

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"/></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"/></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
// This sample uses the Autocomplete widget to help the user select a
// place, then it retrieves the address components associated with that
// place, and then it populates the form fields with those details.
// This sample requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
  // geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode']});

  // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
  // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
  autocomplete.setFields('address_components');

  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details,
  // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
          {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#########MY_API_KEY##############&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have to put the sessionId into the src reference. 
Like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#########MY_API_KEY##############&sessiontoken=####&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

Notice I have added **&sessiontoken=####** after the api key.

Google recommends using a UUID as the session token.
The following is a function to get UUID taken from here: [GooglePlaces Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345848/google-places-autocomplete-included-with-places-details-sku-is-not-getting-tri)

```
var UUID = (function() {
  var self = {};
  var lut = [];
  for (var i=0; i<256; i++) { lut[i] = (i<16?'0':'')+(i).toString(16); }
  self.generate = function() {
      var d0 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      var d1 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      var d2 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      var d3 = Math.random()*0xffffffff|0;
      return lut[d0&0xff]+lut[d0>>8&0xff]+lut[d0>>16&0xff]+lut[d0>>24&0xff]+'-'+
        lut[d1&0xff]+lut[d1>>8&0xff]+'-'+lut[d1>>16&0x0f|0x40]+lut[d1>>24&0xff]+'-'+
        lut[d2&0x3f|0x80]+lut[d2>>8&0xff]+'-'+lut[d2>>16&0xff]+lut[d2>>24&0xff]+
        lut[d3&0xff]+lut[d3>>8&0xff]+lut[d3>>16&0xff]+lut[d3>>24&0xff];
  }
  return self;
})();
```

Google also has an util endpoint that should give you a sessiontoken: require('@google/maps').util.placesAutoCompleteSessionToken()